# How to return data from AngularFirestore using where

Tags: ionic4, angularfire2

I'm trying to create an Ionic 4 mobile app using AngularFire2. I can authenticate, insert, delete, update documents with no problem. However I can't seem to return any data i subscribe to from Firebase when using "ref.where".

I want to get the data of the document that matches my search query.

I've tried various guides found online.

Client side:

```
async test() {
  await this.crudService.check_organization_membership(this.userId).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
}
```

Crud Service:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
check_organization_membership(userId) {
return this.firestore.collection('organizations', ref => ref.where('org_members', '==', userId)).snapshotChanges();
}
```

When reading stuff from the firestore i can just subscribe to data and do "data.map(e =>" and return data no problem.

I get Property 'map' does not exist on type when trying to map this in the crudService after SnapshotChange().

Thanks

Comment: snapshotChanges() returns a Observable. But the await keyword requires a promise. I believe that is what causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ranika Nisal answered my question in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096353/how-to-return-data-from-angularfirestore-using-where/58096868#comment102585264_58096353):

> `snapshotChanges()` returns a `Observable`. But the `await` keyword requires a promise. I believe that is what causing the issue